# what is the mongoose equivalent for the SQL query

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, mongoose, querying

```
select _id from project where projectName = '***' order by viewCount desc limit 5
```

i'm still new to mongoose and have a somewhat intermediate SQL understanding, here's my attempt of it as i'm trying to retrieve the `ObjectId` of the sorted return

```
ProjectModel.find({id}).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(5).exec( 
    function(err, projects) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProjectModel.find({projectName: '***'}, ["_id"]).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(5).exec( 
    function(err, projects) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: what does the `***` mean? if `projectName` is not null, return `_id` and sort it by `viewCount` and limit the results to 5?

Comment: See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find `{projectName: '***'}` is the `where projectName = '***'` equivalent of SQL